# Android Room Database error: Unused parameter: days in @Query function

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I'm using Room databse, trying to write a query in my Dao, which will delete all records older than specific amount of days. Here is what i come to:

```
 @Query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE dateFrom <= date('now','-:days day')")
fun deleteAllOlderThan(days: Int)
```

However, when i try to build my project i get an error in my Gradle Console:

> error: Unused parameter: days

I am using Kotlin, so it also show me this:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':nexo:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>   Internal compiler error. See log for more details

What is wrong with my Query?

**UPDATE**

I am also getting an error about converting Date. Here is my converter:

```
class Converter {
@TypeConverter
fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?) = value?.let { Date(it) }

@TypeConverter
fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?) = date?.time
}
```

I am also adding it to my Database with annotation:

```
@TypeConverters(Converter::class)
```

Here is specific error i get:

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
>   e: 
>   e:private final java.util.Date dateFrom = null;

**SUMMARY**

1. I was trying to use Converter with sealed class which in Room it causes problems, so i decided to keep my date parameter as Long.
2. Check Emmanuel S answer. It should be:

   ```
   @Query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE dateFrom <= date('now', '-' || :days || ' days')")
   fun deleteAllOlderThan(days: Int)
   ```

Comment: I suspect that you cannot use `:days` inside of a quoted string. All Room is doing is wrapping around SQLite placeholders. Try string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this, also see my update if you want, i haven't notice another problem

Comment: post your Database class .. :-)

Comment: @EmanuelS i made an update, thanks for help

Comment: 1) validate that you have the proper Date imported in your converter class. There's sql.Date and util.Date. Maybe you have mixed it. If the error still persists, remove the "open" classes and double check if this may be the issue

Comment: I provide my database with Dagger

Comment: @EmanuelS I made an update. I think the problem is with the converter all the time, the error tells me about it. I am using util.Date in both

Comment: Okay, the reason may be because your LogEvent is a sealed class. That means your Date is "private" and cant be accessed by Room. Try to make it open, not sealed

Comment: Ok, i will try. Here is also the log from my gradle console if you will be interested: https://gist.github.com/oksett/1fa8e4237817f33fba5ab08a767c1cf0

Comment: Tried it. Its the sealed class. Make it to open and it should work. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/52

Comment: Still nothing,  i made it open, and removed dateFrom variable from LogEvent, so the child classes will not override it, now they have just this as own parameter. The error still appears

Comment: @EmanuelS I decided to keep dateFrom as Long, because it is not a big deal. But there is a problem with the query, actually it not works as it should. Can you check it again? There should be minus or something. Thanks for help so far, i will accept your answer if this query will be working

Comment: instead of `:days`, try using `:arg0`

Answer (score 12):

I think CW gave the answer already for your: days issue.

Your days must be quoted as a string like

```
"-20 days"


@Query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE dateFrom <= date('now', :days)")
fun deleteAllOlderThan(days: String)
```

If it's not working, concat may help.

Try:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE dateFrom <= date('now', '-' || :days || ' days')")
fun deleteAllOlderThan(days: Int)
```

For your Converter issue, you may want to use

```
@TypeConverter
fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?) = value?.let { Date(it) }

@TypeConverter
fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?) = date?.time
```

which works just fine.

Don't use a companion object. Just use

```
class DBConverters { 
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?) = value?.let { Date(it) }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?) = date?.time
}
```

and add the Converter to your abstract DB class like

```
@TypeConverters(DBConverters::class)
abstract class YourDb : RoomDatabase() {}
```

Comment: I made an update, maybe you can help now. I also using your convertion

Comment: I made an update, i have error: Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter methods.

Comment: updated my answer. try to use concat. im not sure if the syntax works.

Comment: Glad that i could help you. Please update your Question above with the solution to help others :-)

Comment: Hey, unfortunately i was in a hurry and didn't really check properly the answer. It appears that it delets all the time, not depends on the date. Maybe you can help again?

Comment: ill take a look in 2~ hours

Comment: Thanks, for now i just invoke this function with Long to make it no complicated

Comment: concatenation worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Inside the @Query string you need to put a `:` before days

Answer (score 2):

About error: Unused parameter: days

Currently Room cannot read arguments name when using Kotlin. Try using arg0 or p0 instead, like:

```
 @Query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE dateFrom <= date('now','-:arg0 day')")
 fun deleteAllOlderThan(days: Int)
```

Comment: That's not true, in my project I just need to put `:` in front of the variable name in the @Query statement

Comment: This bug has been fixed in one of Kotlin releases. Unfortunately I do not know which exactly and I am not able to check it now...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

inside build.gradle in the app module.